# Vagrant : Changes edited in host machine's( Windows 10 ) IDE doesnt reflect in guest machine( Ubuntu )

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I am using this vagrant box to test out a python script I am working on

```
    config.vm.box = "mcandre/vagrant-ubuntu-python3"
```

Project root in host machine is c:/pythontest
Vagrantfile is in this root

```
    c:/pythontest/Vagrantfile
```

I placed my python script test.py in c:/pythontest which is by default shared with guest /vagrant

```
    c:/pythontest/test.py
```

For the changes I make in IDE in host machine are not reflecting in guest.

Steps I followed
I make changes in the script
save the script
check the changes in terminal from guest maching using cat

However if I reload vagrant box ( vagrant reload ) , I can see the changes.

I tried below options

```
    config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant"
```

`

```
    config.vm.synced_folder "c:/pythontest", "/vagrant"
```

I get this in output when I up the box ( vagrant up )

```
    ==> default: Rsyncing folder: /cygdrive/c/pythontest/ => /vagrant
```

Here is all the output

```
    Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
    ==> default: Checking if box 'mcandre/vagrant-ubuntu-python3' is up to date...
    ==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
    ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
        default: Adapter 1: nat
    ==> default: Forwarding ports...
        default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
    ==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
    ==> default: Booting VM...
    ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
        default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
        default: SSH username: vagrant
        default: SSH auth method: private key
    ==> default: Machine booted and ready!
    ==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    ==> default: Rsyncing folder: /cygdrive/c/datascience/ => /vagrant
    ==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
    ==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

Can you please help me autosync these changes I make from host machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [vagrant rsync](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/rsync.html) shared folder type so as mentioned in doc

> The rsync synced folder does a one-time one-way sync from the machine
>   running to the machine being started by Vagrant.
>
> The [rsync](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/rsync.html) and [rsync-auto](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/rsync-auto.html) commands can be used to force a resync and to
>   automatically resync when changes occur in the filesystem. Without
>   running these commands, Vagrant only syncs the folders on vagrant up
>   or vagrant reload.

If you do one-time change, you can run the `vagrant rsync` command to make sure your change is sync in the VM.

If you do frequent changes on the host, you should run the `vagrant rsync-auto`, it will detect changes on the host and sync on the VM.